# NatTable cursor switch into selection mode after DND

Tags: drag-and-drop, mouseevent, swt, nattable, nebula

I have nattable with grid. I introduced own drag listener which implements `DragSourceListener`.
DND works well - is possible drag some item and drop it into some group of item. When is drop executes above item which is not valid for drop, nothing happens.

But problem is that after valid or not valid drop is cursor switched into some "selection mode". So both buttons on mouse are not pressed, but when I moving the cursor above cells, then is highlited rectangle which is defined by cell where was executed drop (left mouse button was released) and by actual cursor position. Simply words this behaviour is the same as multi selection of cells by cursor moving with pressed left mouse button. This strange behaviour is possible terminate by click on some cell. Then moving cursor above cells nothing do and remains highlited selected area, which is canceled by another mouse click.
When is dragging canceled by ESC key, so drop is not execute, then this problem not occures.

Summarization - after release left button during dragging the cursor remains in some like selection mode, but mouse buttons are not pressed.

Is needed call something after drop? Some tips for reason of this problem?

Comment: Sorry I don't really get the details. Especially because I don't understand why you implemented a custom DragSourceListener. Do you need to support drag and drop INSIDE a NatTable or do you need it to drag and drop from a NatTable to another control?

Comment: Dirk Fauth: This implementation of custom DragSourceListener is not my work. This listener exists in our application some time already. And answer on your question: we don’t need support drag and drop to another control. We need only DND inside one NatTable.
We have more NatTables, but only in this we need DND, and actual solution is more or less prototype which is maybe not absolutly right wroten.

Comment: We need some own functionality about f.e. decision if drag is valid, or obtain data for dragSetData(). So we have some own methods in this listener. Therefore we have own listener which implements DragSourceListener.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the interactions on dragging an item are mixed up, since you implemented a `DragSourceListener` which is base SWT, and there are drag listeners inside NatTable.

Typically interaction listeners in NatTable should be implemented via NatTable API. As you only want to deal with drag & drop support inside a single NatTable instance, you should implement and register an `IDragMode` similar to the `ColumnReorderDragMode` for example. This way you are under full control what happens inside the NatTable and don't need to deal with SWT drag & drop in combination with NatTable UI bindings.

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply. Your tip sonds good, I will try it.